# Is there historically a clear connection between a better economy and a freer market?

Tags: economy

Where as a better economy is defined as higher GDP per capita. And the ''freedom'' of a market is decided by the amount of taxes.

Comment: Are you looking for a clear connection or a counterexample?   How are you measuring "better economy"? How are you measuring "freer market"?    This is easily a book length answer. Just defining the terms will take a very long essay.  The answer will also depend on the historical period; capitalism doesn't flourish under autocracy; Marxism is only possible in a post-scarcity market (and Marxists will claim their economy is freer than capitalist).

Comment: Fascinating question, but definitely book length - and tax level is very definitely not a measure of market freedom.